# Excel: How to simplify a growing nested IF AND formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a number of IF AND formula, and they will reach the limit.
What is the best replacement solution?

EG.

```
IF(AND(AC9=1,AC4=(AB4+7)),1&"b",
IF(AND(AC9=2,AC4=(AB4+7)),2&"b",
IF(AND(AC9=3,AC4=(AB4+7)),3&"b",
IF(AND(AC9=4,AC4=(AB4+7)),4&"b",
IF(AND(AC9=5,AC4=(AB4+7)),5&"b",)))))
```

or simpler

```
IF(AB18=1,(100%+AB17)*($D$271*AB16),
IF(AB18=2,(100%+AB17)*($E$271*AB16),
IF(AB18=3,(100%+AB17)*($F$271*AB16),
IF(AB18=4,(100%+AB17)*($G$271*AB16),
IF(AB18=5,(100%+AB17)*($H$271*AB16),)))))
```

All the variables are held in multiple rows
The top row is numbered 1,2,3,4 etc.

The nested functions work fine, but the number of options I can offer are limited.
Are there particular functions that we can turn to in these situations?

Comment: You could write your own macro functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to turn this into a lookup.  Here is the gist with an example similar to your first problem.

I kept everything at the beginning of the spreadsheet for simplicity.  Your AC9 is my C1.  Your AC4 is my D1.  I just stuck a result in D1 equal to `AB4+7` (I just made up what that result would be).

[image]

You want to assign values if AC9 is a number in a certain range and AC4 equals a certain value.  I handle the AND requirement by concatenating the two.

Columns F and G contain a lookup table.  You can expand the table as needed.  In a case like this, you could use a formula that you replicate to populate the table as needed.  For example, your F1 formula could be:

```
=ROW()&$AB$4+7
```

Copying that down the column would use the row number to increment your target AC9 value, and concatenate that to the target value of `AB4+7`.

Column G contains the value you want.  So you could use a formula like:

```
=ROW()&"b"
```

Copying that down the column will populate you result values.

To do the lookup, my formula in A1 is:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$1&$D$1,$F$1:$G$5,2,0),"")
```

This creates a lookup value by concatenating the current values of C1 and D1 in my spreadsheet, and comparing that to the values in column F, looking for an exact match.  If it finds a match, it pulls the associated value from column G.

If there is no match, the lookup will produce an error.  Wrapping the VLOOKUP with IFERROR assigns a null result if there is an error (no match).

Your second example doesn't even require concatenation, just a lookup table containing the numbers to compare AB18 against, and the associated calculation as the result.

Comment: Thanks very much for this advice... It should stand me in good stead... I'm going to now try and implement this solution... I'll post back on how I got on.

Comment: This has been a great help to me... thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

fixer123 may have provided the best solution for you using a vlookup against a table.

Another possible approach if you wanted to use a similar version of your formula and can't have a lookup table might be using pretty close to the same formula you had

```
=IF(AND(AC9<=5,AC4=(AB4+7)),AC9&"b")
```

Your other example you might achieve with something like this which determines the cell address to multiply by

```
=IF(AB18<=5,(100%+AB17)*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(271,AB18+3))*AB16))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked and while being very grateful for all assistance... and fixer1234 definitely opened up my mind to other alternatives ,.. I have to say that, you saw the pure answers... I've just tested it now on the version of the period... it obviously creates an additional host of 0b's, but with a little mod, those could be eliminated... very nice one liners .. thanks for sharing :)